# .find with OR operator to listen for a change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to find a solution and have came across little to no example of what I am trying to do,

We are wanting a .find to have a OR operator with a .change event, all methods I have tried below do not work, any suggestions?

In short:if any of the 1-5 check-box's inside the div "personalisation-embroidery-choices' is checked, it triggers the removal of a class and attribute of check-box 6.

```
$('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(0)' || ':checkbox:eq(1)'  || ':checkbox:eq(2)' || ':checkbox:eq(3)' || ':checkbox:eq(4)' || ':checkbox:eq(5)').change(function(){ // on change of state
    if(this.checked) // if changed state is "CHECKED"
    {
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(6)').removeClass('wapf-checked');
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(6)').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Currently, the the trigger of removing the class and attribute of check-box 6 is only triggered if check-box (0) is clicked.

I Have even tried doing the `.find()` selectors by comma separation '..' , '..' and '[..], ..

Another function which removes 1-5 if the 6'th is clicked - works fine

```
$('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(6)').change(function(){ // on change of state
    if(this.checked) // if changed state is "CHECKED"
    {
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(0)').removeClass('wapf-checked');
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(1)').removeClass('wapf-checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(2)').removeClass('wapf-checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(3)').removeClass('wapf-checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(4)').removeClass('wapf-checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find('.wapf-swatch:eq(5)').removeClass('wapf-checked');
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(0)').removeAttr('checked');
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(1)').removeAttr('checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(2)').removeAttr('checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(3)').removeAttr('checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(4)').removeAttr('checked'); 
        $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(5)').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-multi-image-swatch field-657045e1ddc01 personalisation-embroidery-choices has-conditions" style="width:100%;" for="657045e1ddc01" data-wapf-d="[{&quot;rules&quot;:[{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;657045e1ddb9c&quot;,&quot;condition&quot;:&quot;==&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;mtctr&quot;,&quot;generated&quot;:false}]}]">
    <div class="wapf-field-label" id="uqID2">
        <label><span>Embroidery</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="wapf-field-input">
        <div class="wapf-image-swatch-wrapper wapf-swatch-wrapper wapf-col--4" style="--wapf-cols:4;--wapf-cols-t:4;--wapf-cols-m:4">
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
                <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="657045e1ddc01" value="0" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-25a5p" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="25a5p" data-wapf-label="Left Breast" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Left Breast  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-xha9q" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="xha9q" data-wapf-label="Large Front" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="7">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Large Front  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£7.00)</span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap wapf-checked" data-dir="t">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-6km5l" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="6km5l" data-wapf-label="Large Back" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="7">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Large Back  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£7.00)</span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-fhkzc" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="fhkzc" data-wapf-label="Back of Neck" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Back of Neck  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-trytc" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="trytc" data-wapf-label="Left Arm" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Left Arm  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-n6y5g" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="n6y5g" data-wapf-label="Right Arm" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Right Arm  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
                <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-uhhg8" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="uhhg8" data-wapf-label="No Embroidery">
                <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>No Embroidery</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can create a working example of the problem

Comment: I have added the HTML. Please note do not try to add id's to any of the div's, inputs etc... these are dynamically created via a WP Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the checked checkbox length (0-5) under `personalisation-embroidery-choices` and if it > 0 then do the stuff over 6 and same for 6th one only

Do like this:

```
$('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6))').change(function() {
  if ($('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6)):checked').length > 0) {
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(6)').removeClass('wapf-checked');
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(6)').prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:eq(6)').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6))').removeClass('wapf-checked');
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6))').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6))').change(function() {
  if ($('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6)):checked').length > 0) {
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(6)').removeClass('wapf-checked');
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices').find(':checkbox:eq(6)').prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:eq(6)').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6))').removeClass('wapf-checked');
    $('.personalisation-embroidery-choices :checkbox:not(:eq(6))').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-multi-image-swatch field-657045e1ddc01 personalisation-embroidery-choices has-conditions" style="width:100%;" for="657045e1ddc01" data-wapf-d="[{&quot;rules&quot;:[{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;657045e1ddb9c&quot;,&quot;condition&quot;:&quot;==&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;mtctr&quot;,&quot;generated&quot;:false}]}]">
  <div class="wapf-field-label" id="uqID2">
    <label><span>Embroidery</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="wapf-field-input">
    <div class="wapf-image-swatch-wrapper wapf-swatch-wrapper wapf-col--4" style="--wapf-cols:4;--wapf-cols-t:4;--wapf-cols-m:4">
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
        <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="657045e1ddc01" value="0" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-25a5p" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="25a5p" data-wapf-label="Left Breast" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Left Breast  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-xha9q" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="xha9q" data-wapf-label="Large Front" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="7">
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Large Front  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£7.00)</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap wapf-checked" data-dir="t">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-6km5l" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="6km5l" data-wapf-label="Large Back" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="7">
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Large Back  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£7.00)</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-fhkzc" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="fhkzc" data-wapf-label="Back of Neck" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Back of Neck  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-trytc" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="trytc" data-wapf-label="Left Arm" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Left Arm  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image has-pricing wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-n6y5g" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="n6y5g" data-wapf-label="Right Arm" data-wapf-pricetype="qt" data-wapf-price="3.5">
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Right Arm  <span class="wapf-pricing-hint">(+£3.50)</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-tt-wrap" data-dir="t">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wapf-2916-657045e1ddc01-uhhg8" name="wapf[field_657045e1ddc01][]" class="wapf-input input-657045e1ddc01 wapf-checked" data-field-id="657045e1ddc01" value="uhhg8" data-wapf-label="No Embroidery" checked>
        <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none" class="wapf-tt-content"><span class="wapf-ttp"><span>No Embroidery</span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```